# How to subtract one dataframe from another

Tags: r

I have a dataframe from which I create a subset. I want to subtract that subset from the dataframe and then use the dataframe for other subsetting. How can this be done?

Example:

```
     Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4
Row1
Row2
Row3
Row4
```

The subset I want is:

```
     Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4
Row1
Row2
```

and I want to be left with

```
     Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4
Row3
Row4
```

This is an example of a much bigger dataset and really I'm not looking for an answer does a subset A and then creates another subset that is not subset A. Is there a way of doing something like `dataframe<-dataframe-subset?`

Comment: `split(dataframe, c(1,1,2,2)`

Comment: Are you trying to filter the dataframe to be only Row1 and Row2 and create a separate dataframe of only Row3 and Row4? Using the word subtract makes your question unclear.

Comment: There are any number of ways to do this. You could just use hard index references to assign the 2 subset dataframes and `rm` the original.

Comment: If you're not changing the row names of your subset, you can just do `newdf <- df[-row.names(subset),]`

Comment: create df: `df <- data.frame(x=1:10,y=1:10)`, create subset: `df1<-df[1:5,]`, deduct: `df[-(1:nrow(df1)), ]`.

Comment: Do you have any way to identify the rows?  Do the row names in one data frame correspond to the row names in the other data frame?  Is there a unique id column?  Are the rows unique in the original data frame?  The answers could vary quite a bit depending on the answers to these questions.  The questino should clarify this and also have an example of input and output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try

```
final_df <- org_df[ !(org_df$ID %in% sub_df$ID), ]
```

Comment: This does not look like a complete answer. When he starts off he only has an original dataframe and he didn't mention anything about unique ID's. You might want to re-write this a bit.

Comment: There are no unique ID's. Some of the original dataframe rows may have the same ID's which is why I didnt mention it

Comment: use `rownames(org_df)` instead?

Answer (score 4):

```
library(dplyr)
want<-anti_join(org_df,sub_df)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another possible way :

Example ->

```
# Load sqldf library
library(sqldf)

# Create an example Data Frame
A <- data.frame(x=c("LA","NY","DC","SA"),
                y=c('a','b','c','d'),
                z = c(10,20,30,40),
                m = c('A','B','C','D'))

# Here is how Data Frame A looks like 
 A
   x y  z m
1 LA a 10 A
2 NY b 20 B
3 DC c 30 C
4 SA d 40 D

# Rows to subtract
rowsToSubset <- c("1","2")

# Just converting rows to subtract as a data frame
rowsToSubsetDF <- data.frame(rowsToSubset)

# Use sqldf to subtract
B <- sqldf("SELECT t.* FROM A t WHERE t.row_names IN (SELECT
            rowsToSubset FROM rowsToSubsetDF)",row.names = TRUE)

# Here is how B looks like
B
   x y  z m
1 LA a 10 A
2 NY b 20 B

# Now perform the second subtraction using sqldf
sqldf("select * from A except select * from B")

    x y  z m
1 DC c 30 C
2 SA d 40 D
```